# Is it possible to disapper the border of image button at particlualr selected areas in android?

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to set a border for few of the image buttons for a particular screen layout in android. But for some buttons, I want to disable the border if the screen-layout background is blue colour. Please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**(I assume you design your app with Material Theme)**

I think you can't do it (maybe possible with some hacky technique), because it's not intended to be that way.

Google has designed each view to underline each of their own purposes. So, I believe, If you can modify a button that way, it won't felt like a button to users thus can raise some misunderstanding.

What possibly user think if such button that doesn't have default blue, exist? Do they still think that as a `Button`?

Personally, I suggest that you leave the border as-is, if you still intended to make it feels like a `Button`.

Otherwise, if you really need it, you can always use `CardView`, put an `ImageView` inside it and attach `OnClickListener` to it. I think the result is quite similar because almost every rectangular view Google has nowadays, got similar visual to `CardView`.

Btw, I made this in my recent project to achieve a borderless `Button`-ey Image. Maybe it'll help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardElevation="4dp"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:contentPadding="0dp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/clickable_photo_thumbnail_image_view"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/photo_thumbnail_size"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/photo_thumbnail_size"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**(UPDATE) This is the screenshot from my app, produced with above code:**

(In my screenshot, I already use a `RecyclerView`)

[image]

Comment: Thanks Moses Aprico